# How to push a view controller safely from a completion block?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, parse-platform

So I have a table view, and in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method, I want to push a view controller based on what row is selected. To determine which view to push, though, I need to perform a Parse (I'm using the parse.com backend for my app) background fetch, and I want to perform the push in the completion handler for this query. The problem, though, is that if I tap the button multiple times, then upon completion multiple views are pushed onto my navigation stack, with the following code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
// call super because we're a custom subclass.
[super tableView:tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
UserDetailsViewController *controller = [[DetailsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil
                                                                                    bundle:nil];
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];
[query includeKey:@"key1"];
[query whereKey:@"key2" containsString:((UILabel *)(cell.contentView.subviews[1])).text];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error){
    Model *model = [[Model alloc] initWithPFObject:[objects objectAtIndex:0]];
    controller.annotation = model;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
}];
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

How do I lock onto the completion block to only perform the push once, for let's say the first tapped indexPath, even if a user taps on many rows all one after the other before the push occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error){
    if (self.navigationController.topViewController == self) {
        Model *model = [[Model alloc] initWithPFObject:[objects objectAtIndex:0]];
        controller.annotation = model;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
    }
}];
```

This way it won't push if you already have another view controller on top of `self`. And also make sure that you are doing all this on the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

There are number of way to do it
one of them is

Take a instance `BOOL isRowSelectedToViewPush`; // set isRowSelectedToViewPush = NO; in viewWillAppear method

And

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // call super because we're a custom subclass.
    if(!isRowSelectedToViewPush ) {
    isRowSelectedToViewPush = YES;
    [super tableView:tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UserDetailsViewController *controller = [[DetailsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil
                                                                                        bundle:nil];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];
    [query includeKey:@"key1"];
    [query whereKey:@"key2" containsString:((UILabel *)(cell.contentView.subviews[1])).text];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error){
        Model *model = [[Model alloc] initWithPFObject:[objects objectAtIndex:0]];
        controller.annotation = model;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    }];

    }
 }
```